# Which one is a better way to check internet connection in android in given below functions?

Tags: android

If we are using any type of internet connection than It is better to check internet connectivity status before making any HTTP Requests to avoid http exceptions. we can do this in given way

1- We can use the below function/method

```
public static boolean getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
        int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
        boolean status = false;
        if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
            status = true;
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            status = true;
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            status = false;
        }
        return status;
    }
```

where `NetworkUtil` is as follows

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkUtil {

    public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
    public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


    public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                return TYPE_WIFI;

            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return TYPE_MOBILE;
        } 
        return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }
}
```

**V/S**

2- We can use the below function/method

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
```

**QUESTION==>** My question is which one is a **better practice** to use the function/method as in the first function/method we are only interested in mobile or wifi status however in second function/method we are checking for available connection information!

Comment: I would like to go with ConnectivityManager Class

Comment: @Kedarnath ji will it make more appropriate to use ConnectivityManager  as by means method 2?

Comment: Yes , I will go with second method. Btw, after Java,Android come, functions are known as Methods.

Comment: @Kedarnath ji many thanks for the comment/answer!!

Comment: You welcome Jiteshbhai Ji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you refer `NetworkUtil` in this [github](https://github.com/viralpatel/android-network-change-detect-example/blob/master/src/net/viralpatel/network/NetworkUtil.java), it is not part of Android SDK;  `ConnectivityManager` is (Added in API Level 1, i.e. from the very beginning of Android SDK).

Always use Android SDK functions instead of 3rd party libraries if possible, as there will be better support, and compatible with future Android OS.

In short, use `ConnectivityManager` until it is deprecated.

Reference: [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

Comment: yes you are correct i am following the same link so means using method 2 is better?

Comment: Yes. Use `ConnectivityManager` (I mentioned in answer).